# Split comma separated values of two column by mapping them into new row using SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
ID        NAME          COMMENTS
1          ABC           HI
2,3        DEF,GHI       HELLO
4          JKL           HII
5,6,7      M,N,O         HEY
```

I've the the above mentioned data in my table with comma separated values, these comma separated values are mapped sequentially.
For Eg. id 1 is related to ABC, 2 is related to DEF and 3 is mapped to GHI and so on.

I want to use the sql query to get the below output:

```
ID        NAME      COMMENTS
1          ABC        HI
2          DEF        HELLO
3          GHI        HELLO
4          JKL        HII
5          M          HEY
6          N          HEY
7          O          HEY
```

Comment: mysql and SQL server are different - which is it?

Comment: @JenR   ...    SQL Server

Comment: There are any number of "SplitString()" table valued functions you can use to do this... it's a pretty common thing. You just call CROSS APPLY using the function and voila.  This could arguably be considered a duplicate question.

Comment: @pmbAustin  i know the application of CROSS APPLY where we have comma separated values in one column, here i'm having values in  multiple columns.Let me know , if you have any link associated to this problem

Comment: that was @pmbAustin

Answer (score 5):

In SQL Server 2016+ you can use `string_split()`.

Before SQL Server 2016, you need some other way to split strings. Using a CSV Splitter table valued function by Jeff Moden:

```
select 
    id = i.item
  , name = n.item
  , comments = t.comments
from t
  cross apply dbo.delimitedsplit8k(t.id,',') i
  cross apply dbo.delimitedsplit8k(t.name,',') n
where i.itemnumber = n.itemnumber
```

rextester **demo**: http://rextester.com/EEFRS3810

returns:

```
+----+------+----------+
| id | name | comments |
+----+------+----------+
|  1 | ABC  | HI       |
|  2 | DEF  | HELLO    |
|  3 | GHI  | HELLO    |
|  4 | JKL  | HII      |
|  5 | M    | HEY      |
|  6 | N    | HEY      |
|  7 | O    | HEY      |
+----+------+----------+
```

splitting strings reference:

- [Tally OH! An Improved SQL 8K “CSV Splitter” Function - Jeff Moden](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/)
- [Splitting Strings : A Follow-Up - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-follow-up)
- [Split strings the right way – or the next best way - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings)
- [**`string_split()`** in SQL Server 2016 : Follow-Up #1 - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2016/04/sql-server-2016/string-split-follow-up-1)

---

using John Cappelletti's in-line xml string splitter:

```
select 
    id = i.RetVal
  , name = n.RetVal
  , comments = t.comments
from t
   Cross Apply (
                Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
                      ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
                From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(t.[Id],',','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as x
                Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
             ) i
   Cross Apply (
                Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
                      ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
                From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(t.[Name],',','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as x
                Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
             ) n
where i.RetSeq = n.RetSeq
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/ZCKVNV72753

Comment: The thing I like best about Jeff Moden's splitter is that it is the ONLY one to include the position number. This is such a critical component of a splitter and most of them miss this simple addition. Even the new string_split does not include this value. Not really sure why that is.

Comment: @SeanLange Very good point. iirc John Cappelletti includes a position number in both his inline xml and itvf string splitter function (lesser posted, but it's out there). I'd also bet he'll come along sooner or later and post it here as the in-line alternative ^.^

Comment: @SeanLange  can you provide me the direct sql query without use of any function and SP.

Comment: @WeIrDo Updated with an inline version. Doesn't look like John is active at the moment.

Comment: @SqlZim Just thrilled you spelled my name correctly  :) +1

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Only because I can use the same cadence as when spelling mississippi!

Comment: @JohnCappelletti, I think about *which one was doubled?* and then I remember *Oh, just all of them!* :-D

Comment: Yes the splitter from @JohnCappelletti does include the position and his splitter is a good one too. :)

Comment: @SeanLange Full disclosure... On a sample of 5,000 records with an average of 20 items each, the TALLY approach was 20ms faster .... BUT, on the other hand, the XML version is not limited to 8K

Comment: @JohnCappelletti I figured it would be a little bit slower when the rows start having more items. But yours is a useful addition to my toolbox in some situations. I have been using the Jeff Moden splitter for so long that it is my go to thought.

Comment: @SeanLange  You are correct, I use both depending on my needs.  However, I tend to parse limited parameters from my apps.  The Tally approach was a real eye-opener for me.  I even went back and re-tooled procedures and functions to take advantage of his brilliant technique.   Pride of authorship is long gone for me.  When I see a good idea, I'll use it.

Comment: @SeanLange Have you tried Eirikur's DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD? For those on 2012+ It's a little faster. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/SQL+Server+2012/106903/

Comment: @AlanBurstein I have checked it out and it looks pretty sweet. Unfortunately some of our production boxes are still using 2008R2....ugh!!!

Answer (score 1):

If you have 4 or less delimited items you could split them using parsename. For 4 items or less this is the fastest method available:

**Sample data and solution**

```
-- Sample data
DECLARE @yourTable TABLE
(
  ID       varchar(100),
  Name     varchar(100),
  Comments varchar(100)
);

INSERT @yourTable VALUES 
  ('1','ABC','HI'),('2,3','DEF,GHI','HELLO'),('4','JKL','HII'),('5,6,7','M,N,O','HEY');

-- solution using parsename for splitting
SELECT 
  ID   = id_new,
  Name = name_new,
  Comments
FROM @yourTable
CROSS JOIN (VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4)) t(N)
CROSS APPLY 
(VALUES 
  (parsename(REPLACE(ID,',','.'), t.N), parsename(REPLACE(Name,',','.'), t.N))
) AS x(id_new, name_new)
WHERE id_new IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY id_new; -- for presentation only, not required and will slow you down
```

**Results**

```
ID   Name  Comments
---- ----- -----------
1    ABC   HI
2    DEF   HELLO
3    GHI   HELLO
4    JKL   HII
5    M     HEY
6    N     HEY
7    O     HEY
```

**Execution Plan**
[image]